# Nokogiri iterating over tr tags too many times

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm scraping this page https://www.library.uq.edu.au/uqlsm/availablepcsembed.php?branch=Duhig and for each `tr` I am collecting and returning the level name and the number of computers available.

The problem is that it is being iterated over too many times. There are only 4 `tr` tags but the loop goes through 5 iterations. This causes an extra `nil` to be appended to the return array. Why is this?

**Scraped Section:**

```
<table class="chart">
    <tr valign="middle">
        <td class="left"><a href="availablepcsembed.php?branch=Duhig&room=Lvl1">Level 1</a></td>
        <td class="middle"><div style="width:68%;"><strong>68%</strong></div></td>
        <td class="right">23 Free of 34 PC's</td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="middle">
        <td class="left"><a href="availablepcsembed.php?branch=Duhig&room=Lvl2">Level 2</a></td>
        <td class="middle"><div style="width:78%;"><strong>78%</strong></div></td>
        <td class="right">83 Free of 107 PC's</td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="middle">
        <td class="left"><a href="availablepcsembed.php?branch=Duhig&room=Lvl4">Level 4</a></td>
        <td class="middle"><div style="width:64%;"><strong>64%</strong></div></td>
        <td class="right">9 Free of 14 PC's</td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="middle">
        <td class="left"><a href="availablepcsembed.php?branch=Duhig&room=Lvl5">Level 5</a></td>
        <td class="middle"><div style="width:97%;"><strong>97%</strong></div></td>
        <td class="right">28 Free of 29 PC's</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Shortened Method:**

```
def self.scrape_details_page(library_url)
    details_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(library_url))

    library_name = details_page.css("h3")

    details_page.css("table tr").collect do |level|
        case level.css("a[href]").text.downcase
            when "level 1"
                name = level.css("a[href]").text
                total_available = level.css(".right").text.split(" ")[0]
                out_of_available = level.css(".right").text.split(" ")[3]
                level = {name: name, total_available: total_available, out_of_available: out_of_available}
            when "level 2"
                name = level.css("a[href]").text
                total_available = level.css(".right").text.split(" ")[0]
                out_of_available = level.css(".right").text.split(" ")[3]
                level = {name: name, total_available: total_available, out_of_available: out_of_available}
         end
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the class attribute of the table and then access the `tr` tags inside, this way you avoid the "additional" tr, like:

```
details_page.css("table.chart tr").map do |level|
  ...
```

And simplify a little bit the `scrape_details_page` method:

```
def scrape_details_page(library_url)
  details_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(library_url))
  details_page.css('table.chart tr').map do |level|
    right = level.css('.right').text.split
    { name: level.css('a[href]').text, total_available: right[0], out_of_available: right[3] }
  end
end

p scrape_details_page('https://www.library.uq.edu.au/uqlsm/availablepcsembed.php?branch=Duhig')

# [{:name=>"Level 1", :total_available=>"22", :out_of_available=>"34"},
#  {:name=>"Level 2", :total_available=>"98", :out_of_available=>"107"},
#  {:name=>"Level 4", :total_available=>"12", :out_of_available=>"14"},
#  {:name=>"Level 5", :total_available=>"26", :out_of_available=>"29"}]
```